How to update existing client app in azure using terraform
I had created client app manually and now I want to update redirect_uris using terraform, Is this possible and how to do it? I know import can help me but how to use it in this code?
resource "azuread_application" "update" created new client app.
I have a below code
data "azuread_application" "app" {
  display_name = "app-name"
}
resource "azuread_application" "update" {
  display_name = data.azuread_application.app.display_name
  object_id    = data.azuread_application.app.id
  web {
    redirect_uris = [
      "https://..........",
    ]
  }
}

terraform plan -var-file ../dev.tfvars

Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute

  with azuread_application.update,
  on main.tf line 20, in resource "azuread_application" "update":
 113:   object_id    = data.azuread_application.app.id

Can't configure a value for "object_id": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.


Look at this documentation first: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application. You're trying to pass a value that isn't expected


Updating existing client app in azure using terraform

Thanks MyName for guiding in the right direction. The main issue seems to be the way you define resources inside azuread_application as per the terraform registry we need to define the app name alone where you also included object_id which results in the blocker.
I tried an updated configuration where I removed the object_id reference and I was able to add the redirect URL successfully.
Configuration:
data "azuread_application" "app" {
  display_name = "GraphApiMvcApp"
}

resource "azuread_application" "update" {
  display_name = data.azuread_application.app.display_name

  web {
    redirect_uris = [
      "https://new-******************************",
    ]
  }
}

Deployment:


Refer:
azuread_application | Resources | hashicorp/azuread | Terraform | Terraform Registry
Redirect URI (reply URL) best practices and limitations - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Learn
